# style h1 inside a div

Tags: html, css

I want to style a h1 headline inside a div, but no matter what I try it always remains bold.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6EtB/1/)

```css
.header h1 {
  font-style: normal;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`font-style` has [nothing to do with bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style):

> The font-style CSS property allows italic or oblique faces to be selected within a font-family.

You want [`font-weight` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight):

> The font-weight CSS property specifies the weight or boldness of the font. However, some fonts are not available in all weights; some are available only on normal and bold.

Answer (score 15):

You need `font-weight`:

```
.header h1{
    color: grey;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h6EtB/2/